# Can't deploy war with TomEE 1.7.3 (tomcat 7.0.52 with drop-in TomEE war)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat7, apache-tomee, thredds

I am running tomcat 7.0.52 on a ubuntu 14.04 server with Java SE 1.8 (build 1.8.0_66-b17). Tomcat is running, manager works and I deployed two wars - a Vaadin application and the THREDDS war version 4.6 (see [unidata TDS](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/thredds/current/tds/TDS.html)). Both applications work.

Now I am adding the TomEE drop-in war (1.7.3) to tomcat7 (I want to add CDI and other Java EE functions to my Vaadin application in the future). When I restart tomcat7, tomee works (I can open the /tomee page), but tomcat can't deploy the THREDDS war anymore.

Here is the output of catalina.out:

```
INFO: ------------------------- localhost -> /thredds
Dec 10, 2015 12:56:14 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader startInternal
SEVERE: LifecycleException 
java.lang.IllegalAccessError
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.LazyStopWebappClassLoader.<init>(LazyStopWebappClassLoader.java:75)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.createClassLoader(WebappLoader.java:730)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.startInternal(WebappLoader.java:582)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader.startInternal(VirtualWebappLoader.java:191)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.ProvisioningWebappLoader.startInternal(ProvisioningWebappLoader.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.LazyStopLoader.start(LazyStopLoader.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5332)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Dec 10, 2015 12:56:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/thredds]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [ProvisioningWebappLoader[/thredds]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.LazyStopLoader.start(LazyStopLoader.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5332)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: start: 
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.startInternal(WebappLoader.java:630)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader.startInternal(VirtualWebappLoader.java:191)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.ProvisioningWebappLoader.startInternal(ProvisioningWebappLoader.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.LazyStopWebappClassLoader.<init>(LazyStopWebappClassLoader.java:75)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.createClassLoader(WebappLoader.java:730)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.startInternal(WebappLoader.java:582)
... 16 more

Dec 10, 2015 12:56:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/thredds.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/thredds]]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is the output of localhost.2015-...:

```
Dec 10, 2015 12:56:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class websocket.drawboard.DrawboardContextListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/websocket/Endpoint
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2944)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1208)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
at websocket.drawboard.DrawboardContextListener.contextDestroyed(DrawboardContextListener.java:32)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5014)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5659)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.websocket.Endpoint
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
... 17 more

Dec 10, 2015 12:56:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
Dec 10, 2015 12:56:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
Dec 10, 2015 12:56:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Dec 10, 2015 12:56:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Dec 10, 2015 12:56:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@54187756')
```

Why is the javax.websocket.Endpoint class missing when I add tomee? Do I have to change classpath for tomee? Any suggestions?